# snapd-desktop-integration flooding syslog

Tags: snap, desktop-environments, gtk3

snapd-desktop-integration on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop system is flooding my syslog here with these messages:

```
Dec  2 14:19:35 server1 systemd[65032]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 322.
Dec  2 14:19:35 server1 systemd[65032]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Dec  2 14:19:35 server1 systemd[65032]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Dec  2 14:19:35 server1 snapd-desktop-i[84480]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Dec  2 14:19:37 server1 systemd[65032]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 323.
Dec  2 14:19:37 server1 systemd[65032]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Dec  2 14:19:37 server1 systemd[65032]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Dec  2 14:19:37 server1 snapd-desktop-i[84540]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
```

I have no clue what this is about, everything seems to be working.

How can I get rid of these messages - or how can I tell the system not to load the module atk-bridge?

Comment: This is happening to us as well:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443676/snapd-desktop-integration-syslog-spam

Comment: Please see [snapd-desktop-integration syslog spam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443676/snapd-desktop-integration-syslog-spam/1443839#1443839) regarding the "atk-bridge" messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [snapd-desktop-integration syslog spam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443676/snapd-desktop-integration-syslog-spam)

Answer (score 4):

For now, I did `snap remove snapd-desktop-integration`, and the log spam went away.  I'm not sure how important that package is, but I can reinstall it after the problem is fixed if it is needed for anything.

Comment: Yeah, this app shouldn't run in level 3.