# snapd-desktop-integration syslog spam

Tags: 22.04

For the past three days we are getting log spammed with these messages every few seconds from almost all of our machines:

```
2 11:13:59 11:13:59 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2823704]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:00 11:14:00 ZT1 daemon.5 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:00 11:14:00 ZT1 daemon.4 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:01 11:14:01 PATG daemon.5 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:01 11:14:01 PATG daemon.4 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:01 11:14:01 E450 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[397538]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:02 11:14:02 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2823808]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:02 11:14:02 ZT1 daemon.5 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:02 11:14:02 ZT1 daemon.4 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:03 11:14:03 PATG daemon.5 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:03 11:14:03 PATG daemon.4 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:03 11:14:03 E450 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[397617]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:04 11:14:04 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2823937]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:05 11:14:05 ZT1 daemon.5 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:05 11:14:05 ZT1 daemon.4 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:05 11:14:05 PATG daemon.5 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:05 11:14:05 PATG daemon.4 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:06 11:14:06 E450 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[397694]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:06 11:14:06 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2824038]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:07 11:14:07 ZT1 daemon.5 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:07 11:14:07 ZT1 daemon.4 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:08 11:14:08 PATG daemon.4 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:08 11:14:08 E450 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[397779]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:08 11:14:08 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2824167]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:09 11:14:09 ZT1 daemon.5 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:09 11:14:09 ZT1 daemon.4 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:10 11:14:10 PATG daemon.5 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:10 11:14:10 PATG daemon.4 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:10 11:14:10 E450 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[397847]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:11 11:14:11 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2824261]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:11 11:14:11 ZT1 daemon.5 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:11 11:14:11 ZT1 daemon.4 systemd[1207]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:12 11:14:12 PATG daemon.5 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2 11:14:12 11:14:12 PATG daemon.4 systemd[5140]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2 11:14:12 11:14:12 E450 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[397915]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
2 11:14:13 11:14:13 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[2824373]:  Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
```

The only updates that we've applied in the time period that these messages started were for passwd and login, so we backed them out:

```
====================================================================

Aptitude 0.8.13: log report
Fri, Dec  2 2022 11:56:27 -0800

  IMPORTANT: this log only lists intended actions; actions which fail
  due to dpkg problems may not be completed.

Will install 1 packages, and remove 0 packages.
========================================
[DOWNGRADE] login:amd64 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1 -> 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2
========================================

Log complete.

=======================================================================

Aptitude 0.8.13: log report
Fri, Dec  2 2022 12:03:00 -0800

  IMPORTANT: this log only lists intended actions; actions which fail
  due to dpkg problems may not be completed.

Will install 1 packages, and remove 0 packages.
4096 B of disk space will be freed
========================================
[HOLD, DEPENDENCIES] login:amd64 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2
[DOWNGRADE] passwd:amd64 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1 -> 1:4.8.1-2ubuntu2
========================================

Log complete.

======================================================================
```

But it made no difference.

We also see repetitive messages like this:

```
 2 12:39:17 12:39:16 E450 daemon.5 systemd[1022]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 2 12:39:17 12:39:16 E450 daemon.4 systemd[1022]:  snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So we're guessing it's possibly something that snapd changed or updated.

It's happening to another user as well:

[snapd-desktop-integration flooding syslog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443595/snapd-desktop-integration-flooding-syslog)

Our systems are all running Ubuntu 22.04.

Would greatly appreciate any hints as to where to look to solve this.

EDIT: See Dan Christensen's answer below for a useful bypass to this problem.

EDIT 2 March 2023: Stable version 2023-02-21 (57) appears to have eliminated the repetitive syslog messages and solved the problem. (Please see my answer below.)

Comment: Just run `init 5` or `systemctl isolate graphical.target` to stop the spam. But it'll back again if your system are not running in level 5.

Comment: @TimeKiller I've already removed snapd-desktop-integration so I can't test that, but thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT 28 February 2023: Stable version 2023-02-21 (57) appears to have eliminated the repetitive syslog messages.  (Please see all the comments under Sergio's answer.)

Here is the repaired version info:

```
~$ snap info snapd-desktop-integration
name:      snapd-desktop-integration
summary:   Desktop Integration for snapd
publisher: Canonical✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/snapd-desktop-integration
contact:   https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration
license:   unset
description: |
Provides a user session daemon used to provide a bridge between the user's session and snapd. 
Used for things like automatic theme installation.
services:
snapd-desktop-integration: simple, enabled, inactive
snap-id:      IrwRHakqtzhFRHJOOPxKVPU0Kk7Erhcu
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 15:17 PST
channels:
latest/stable:    0.1 2023-02-21 (57) 438kB -
latest/candidate: 0.1 2023-02-23 (59) 442kB -
latest/beta:      ↑                         
latest/edge:      0.1 2023-02-23 (59) 442kB -
installed:          0.1            (57) 438kB -`
```

EDIT 21 January 2023: candidate version 57 produces these repetitive syslog messages when we installed it after ssh'ing to a test system:

`21 10:11:52 10:11:52 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261316.069573] audit: type=1107 audit(1674324712.162:358): pid=830 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=1145400 label="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" peer_pid=881 peer_label="unconfined"`

`21 10:11:52 10:11:52 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261316.069573]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=106 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'`

`21 10:11:52 10:11:52 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261316.069831] audit: type=1107 audit(1674324712.162:359): pid=830 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="ListSessions" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=1145400 label="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" peer_pid=881 peer_label="unconfined"`

`21 10:11:52 10:11:52 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261316.069831]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=106 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'`

`21 10:11:54 10:11:54 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[1145502]:  Failed to do gtk init. Waiting for a new session with desktop capabilities.`

`21 10:11:54 10:11:54 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261318.318431] audit: type=1326 audit(1674324714.410:360): auid=1001 uid=1001 gid=1001 ses=152 subj=snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration pid=1145502 comm="snapd-desktop-i" exe="/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57/usr/bin/snapd-desktop-integration" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fb4631a6a3d code=0x50000`

`21 10:11:54 10:11:54 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[1145502]:  Failed to get session list (check that login-session-observe interface is connected). Forcing a reload.`

`21 10:11:54 10:11:54 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261318.321048] audit: type=1107 audit(1674324714.410:361): pid=830 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.3" pid=1145502 label="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" peer_pid=881 peer_label="unconfined"`

`21 10:11:54 10:11:54 ZT1 kern.5 kernel:  [261318.321048]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=106 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'`

`21 10:11:54 10:11:54 ZT1 user.5 snapd-desktop-i[1145502]:  Loop exited. Forcing reload.`

EDIT 3 January 2023: if you are testing candidate version 55 you can stop the repetitive messages by running:

`sudo snap connect snapd-desktop-integration:login-session-observe`

Please see Sergio's comment below.  The goal is to eliminate the need for this step and make it autoconnect.

EDIT 17 December 2022: we tested candidate version 55 on two machines to which we were ssh'd.  It fixed the atk-bridge messages, but caused a different set of messages every few seconds:

`17 10:42:52 10:42:52 PATG user.5 snapd-desktop-i[53867]:  Failed to get session list (check that login-session-observe interface is connected). Forcing a reload.`

`17 10:42:52 10:42:52 PATG user.5 snapd-desktop-i[53867]:  Loop exited. Forcing reload.`

`17 10:42:52 10:42:52 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246586.108424] audit: type=1107 audit(1671302572.982:370): pid=1182 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" memb er="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=53867 label="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" peer_pid=1280 peer_label="unconfined"`

`17 10:42:52 10:42:52 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246586.108424]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'`

`17 10:42:52 10:42:52 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246586.108847] audit: type=1107 audit(1671302572.982:371): pid=1182 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" membe r="ListSessions" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=53867 label="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" peer_pid=1280 peer_label="unconfined"`

`17 10:42:52 10:42:52 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246586.108847]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'`

`17 10:42:55 10:42:55 PATG user.5 snapd-desktop-i[53945]:  Failed to do gtk init. Waiting for a new session with desktop capabilities.`

`17 10:42:55 10:42:55 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246588.351735] audit: type=1326 audit(1671302575.223:372): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=10 subj=snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration pid=53945 comm="snapd-desktop-i" exe="/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/55/usr/bin/snapd-desktop-integration" sig= 0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f0aba0cda3d code=0x50000`

`17 10:42:55 10:42:55 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246588.355602] audit: type=1107 audit(1671302575.227:373): pid=1182 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" memb er="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.11" pid=53945 label="snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration" peer_pid=1280 peer_label="unconfined"`

`17 10:42:55 10:42:55 PATG kern.5 kernel:  [246588.355602]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'`

The sequence repeated every few seconds until we uninstalled the package.  (Both machines had users logged into to graphical sessions at the time we did the test, if that matters.)

EDIT 12 December 2022: candidate version 49 did not fix the repetitive "atk-bridge" messages that occur when you ssh to a machine that has snapd-desktop-integration installed, though it may fix the messages from the GDM session:

https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration/pull/41#issuecomment-1344603344

EDIT 9 December 2022:  Here is the result of testing candidate version 49:

https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration/pull/41#issuecomment-1344589269

EDIT 7 December 2022:  Here is the commit:

https://github.com/sergio-costas/snapd-desktop-integration/commit/a5652377cc5c8f20ea311a0dd28d44a63c4551c2

EDIT 6 December 2022:  Here is the pull request:

https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration/pull/41

The recommendation per the package authors is:

> ...follow the pull request, when that gets merged it will be published to the candidate channel within a couple of hours automatically.

They also add:

> It's a rather complicated fix, that is a bit risky so it will take a couple days to get properly reviewed.  But once it's thoroughly reviewed, we'll get going in the testing process right away.

EDIT 4 December 2022:  I emailed one of the package authors.  They have someone working on the issue and are hopeful they'll have a fix this week.

====

The problem must have been caused by a faulty snap upgrade sometime around 29 November 2022.

Unfortunately the information in `snap changes` is already overwritten.

The repetitive messages stopped on all of our machines at about 2100 GMT on 2 December 2022 but they restarted again today (3 December).

We noticed that the "atk-bridge...please try to not load it" messages start again as soon as we ssh to any of the machines.

We used htop in user tree view to kill off tasks until we could see that it was "systemd --user" repeatedly launching atk-bridge.  If we kill that systemd  task, atk-bridge stops respawning and the atk-bridge syslog messages stop (but not the other ones).

In the meantime, we applied Dan Christensen's bypass (which also gets rid of the atk-bridge messages) so no need to kill off any tasks after ssh'ing.

Comment: What version and revision are you currently running?  It's shown in the last line output by `snap info snapd-desktop-integration`

Comment: Hi Dan, here's what we see on one of the machines:  
  latest/stable:    0.1 2022-12-01 (43) 311kB -
  latest/candidate: 0.1 2022-11-29 (46) 311kB -
  latest/beta:      ↑
  latest/edge:      0.1 2022-11-29 (46) 311kB -
installed:          0.1            (43) 311kB -

Comment: Sorry for the formatting on that.

Comment: That's the same version I have installed, and my logs are still getting spammed.

Comment: Yes mine are too.  See the edit I just made on the answer

Comment: Glad to hear that upstream knows about it.  Is there a bug tracking / issue system where this is being tracked?

Comment: I wasn't able to create an Ubuntu bug report since it's a GitHub project.  So I wrote directly to one of the authors and linked this page.  At present I don't see a separate issue listed there yet though there is an existing one that's somewhat related: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration/issues/23#issuecomment-1335084335

Answer (score 9):

For now, I did `snap remove snapd-desktop-integration`, and the log spam went away.  I'm not sure how important that package is, but I can reinstall it after the problem is fixed if it is needed for anything.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I've done the same

Comment: What functionality do I lose by uninstalling it? What does it do? I had to uninstall it as well. Their site mentions "automatic theme installation"?

Comment: I uninstalled it over a month ago and haven't noticed anything different.  I'd also be curious to know what it is supposed to do...

Comment: With Ubuntu 22.04 LTS this seems to be the only fix which works.  (It spams so much that my journal became plain unusable.  This **is critical**.)  Tried everything else (including `sudo snap connect snapd-desktop-integration:login-session-observe` which probably does not work in 22.04 LTS yet).  AFAICS if desktop integration is missing, you will not get notified about the grace period until things like chromium or firefox are restarted forcibly, thereby killing your unsaved hard work.  YMMV, but restarting my browser takes 1-2 hours (I have 100+ brower windows open .. machine w/ 128 GB RAM)

Answer (score 4):

This happens when snapd-desktop-integration run in non-graphical mode.

To solve it, make snapd-desktop-integration run in graphical mode (level 5) only.

Find the installed reversion (here is 43) by

```bash
snap info snapd-desktop-integration
```

then edit /etc/systemd/system/snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-43.mount

```
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target  # changed
```

then

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl disable snap-snapd\\x2ddesktop\\x2dintegration-43.mount
systemctl enable snap-snapd\\x2ddesktop\\x2dintegration-43.mount 

snap stop snapd-desktop-integration
systemctl isolate graphical.target
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: Thanks very much TK.  Assuming this is specific to version 43, wouldn't the edit need to be redone every time there's an automatic snapd update of the package (unless there's an upstream fix)?

Comment: On the system where I'm having this problem, there *is* a graphical session running as well.  So I'm not sure whether the change above will fix the issue.

Comment: This isn't a general solution. It happens over vnc as well, at runlevel 5.

Answer (score 2):

These messages were due to a limitation in snapd: daemons are launched at the beginning of ANY session. This means that the snapd-desktop-integration daemon was being launched not only in the desktop sessions, but also in the GDM session (but since GDM has its HOME folder outside /home, snapd won't launch it, showing an error) and in remote SSH sessions (in this case, snapd-desktop-integration won't be able to connect to the desktop, because there is no desktop in the session).

The current stable snapd-desktop-integration fixes the first error messages, the ones from the GDM sessions. Also, there is another fix currently in candidate for the second case.

Anyway, none of these errors are critical because, as commented, they happen when there is no desktop where to run snapd-desktop-integration. But, of course, they are a nuisance to have them in the system log. Please, confirm that the fixes work.

Comment: Thank you very much for this and all your work on this product Sergio.

Comment: Sergio we tested candidate version 55.  Please see results in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes... I forgot to comment it: to avoid launching snapd-desktop-integration in non-graphical shells, we connect to the logind daemon. But to do so, the snap requires to be connected to the login-session-observe slot. Currently it isn't connected automatically, so you must connect it manually with


"sudo snap connect snapd-desktop-integration:login-session-observe"


But the idea is to make it autoconnect before this code moves into stable.

Comment: If the slot isn't connected, the daemon behaves like now: in graphical sessions it will work as expected, and in not-graphical sessions it will spit an error every two seconds (this is, each time it is relaunched and fails to connect to the graphical session).

Comment: Thanks Sergio.  If possible, would you let us know here when there's a new version you'd like us to test?

Comment: Of course! But just quick question: did the "sudo snap connect ..." command fix the log comments?

Comment: Hi Sergio, yes.  If we issue the "sudo snap connect ..." command the syslog messages stop.  We tested two different systems to which we were ssh'd.  Thank you again and happy new year!

Comment: Thank you for your reports and time, and happy new year for you too!!

Comment: Hello Sergio...would you make a post here when there is a new version you'd like us to test?  I think many of us here have the snapd-desktop-integration package uninstalled at present to avoid the log spam from ssh sessions, so we won't necessarily know when it's been fixed.

Comment: There is a candidate release that fixes this that you can install if you want. We are right now testing it to promote it to stable.

Comment: OK great!  Thanks very much Sergio.

Comment: It has been promoted to stable, so this should be fully fixed right now.

Comment: That's great to hear. We're out of power at present due to the storms so it may be a few days till we can test that, but looking forward to it!

Comment: We installed stable version 57 on six test systems and it does appear to have stopped the repetitive syslog messages when we ssh.  Thank you for all your work Sergio.  I've updated my answer with the fixed version info.  Is the "inactive" any concern?

Comment: No, the "inactive" is not a problem.